# Create a new date format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want my date to show as `MM.dd.yyyy`. But in SQL Server there is no such format to format your date in this format. What I can do is:

```
select replace(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101), '/', '.')
```

It will give me the expected output. But my question is: can we create a new format all together to display this kind of data without replace?

We have a `dateformat` options from `0` to `131` in SQL Server. Can we create new format like `132` in SQL Server?

Comment: I am guessing the answer is no, in which case, to avoid needing to retype your solution each time, you could use a User Defined Function.

Comment: Formatting data is a job best done in the application/presentation layer rather than in a database query.

Comment: Related - 2008 is now completely unsupported. Someone should be concerned about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL Server [`format()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_format.asp) function.

```
select format(getdate(), 'MM.dd.yyyy') as date
```

Comment: Format is  available in 2012 and above. i am using 2008

Comment: @RedDevil, you can use `concat(month(getdate()), '.', day(getdate()), '.', year(getdate()))`

Comment: @RedDevil . . . You are saying that `fromat()` is available in all currently supported versions of SQL Server.  You should be using a supported version.